# validate if multiple email address entered in a textbox does not contain a comma in between

Tags: c#, regex

I got regular expression for adding comma in between the emails.... But i am not getting the validation if the email address is not separated by comma.Show a validation if multiple email addresses does not contain a comma.And if only one email address is there no comma is needed.

Comment: it's hard to achieve this.

Comment: what's the regular expression you have

Comment: ^((\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*([,])*)*$

Comment: first you can check `','` using `input.contains(',')` then split with `','` and validate individually

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig - That doesn't work - `"james,bond"@007.com` is a valid email address. Note that the double-quotes are part of the address.

Comment: then you should need to amend your requirement.

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig - I'm not the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String input  = "a@b.de, c@x.com, f@d.org,";
String[] adresses = input.Split(',');

foreach(String adress in adresses){
    if (!adress is exactly one email adress){ //your single-adress validation here
      //error
    }
}

//input valid
```

---

as Enigmativity lined out, a `,` in the local part is valid, if wrapped in `"` - so this approach does not work.

Then, only one option is remaining:

- consider the input string malformated all the time, and fix it.
- match every pattern that is a valid email adress according to YOUR convention.
- Buildup a valid string out of these:

Something like:

```
String input = "a@b.de,t@s.com x@y.org;f@m.net";

Regex r = new Regex("\\w+\\@\\w+"); //your pattern here, just example.
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(input);

List<String> adresses = new List<String>();
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    adresses.Add(m.Groups[0].ToString().Trim());
}

String sanitizedInput = String.Join(", ", adresses);
Console.WriteLine(sanitizedInput); //"a@b.de, t@s.com, x@y.org, f@m.net";
Console.Read();
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.... This is checking the validation for email address..... But i need a validation if multiple email addresses does not have a comma in between.

Comment: And is what the code is doing. if one instance of adress (which is ONE adress, if all `,` are present) contains multiple adresses, its not valid.

Comment: You can't split on `','` as `"james,bond"@007.com` is a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, i should be helpful to you.

```
string re = @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
     + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
     + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?
                [0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
     + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

            string emails = "abc@hotmail.com,xyz@com,mnn@gmail.com";

            string[] emailsArr = emails.Split(',');
            foreach (string email in emailsArr)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(email, re))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(email + " this email is valid");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(email + " this email is invalid");

                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
```